# Male circumcision causes eardrum to burst?

Tags: medical-science, children, circumcision, hearing

I have seen a post circulating Facebook which is also cited by this source: http://joseph4gi.blogspot.com/2017/09/drs-may-ask-if-baby-is-circumcised-for.html (The source is clearly biased against the practice of infant circumcision, but that is besides the point of this question.)

Here is the Facebook post in question:

[image]

> Took my son in today to get his infant hearing test done.
>
> Part of their medical questionnaire was if the baby was a male, was he
>   circumcised?
>
> I asked why that was a relevant question and was told because
>   sometimes an ear drum can burst while they are crying during the
>   circumcision.
>
> My heart sank.

Is there any evidence for this? While I found information about pressure (e.g., kissing the baby's ear) to cause a rupture of the ear drum, I found no information on circumcision and ear drum ruptures.

Comment: Did your source give you any evidence?  As it stands, this is not a "notable claim".

Comment: @DanielRHicks this link makes it sound slightly more notable: http://www.savingsons.org/2017/08/ear-drum-rupture-during-circumcision.html

Comment: @Human  So the claim is that because infants are callously circumcised without painkillers their crying sometimes causes their eardrums to burst, resulting in deafness?

Comment: To be honest, I doubt anyone is  going to find anything on this, as it's a random Facebook post claiming what someone told them in the hospital, as well as a distinct lack of any search results beyond the above source.

Comment: I question if this is answerable, but I came here because I had seen the exact same post on social media.  I think it is notable enough.

Answer (score 13):

In a [review article](https://jamanetwork.com/journals/jamapediatrics/fullarticle/1870232) on adverse events in connection with male cicrumcision, no hearing loss was noted in 1.4M subjects... so I'd say that is a myth.

Comment: The study does not seem to me to have looked at hearing loss at all. I see no mention of it. Since they performed a literature review and looked at a number of possible adverse events, that's a hint that this is not a thing that happens, but it's very different from if the study had been open to finding something but had not found it.

Comment: @DanGetz They looked for all possible AE related to male circumcision: ---- "Possible MC AEs for this analysis were identified from
(1) a review of PubMed using the search terms circumcision and
adverse events and (2) the ICD-9 and CPT manuals for condi-
tions that are not necessarily due to but could be related to MC."  ---- if, as the claim states, hearing loss was a known AE for MC, they would have found it that way.

Comment: @DanGetz The original claim was that this is well known in medicine and common enough to be worth putting on a questionnaire. If so then it would certainly have been included in a review article on the subject.